# How to reload current route guards?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a route that has a guard `AdminGuard`, which lets me in only when I'm an admin.

But when I'm on that page and I click `Logout` the state is propagated in all the app via Observables, but I still am in a route, which I am not supposed to be in, since I've been logged out.

How to "reactivate" curent route guards?

Comment: Why don't you simply navigate to the home page after the logout? That would seem quite logical to me.

Comment: Of course that is a solution, but not exactly a solution I am looking for.

Comment: @Humberd Have you found a good solution for your case. I have exactly same issue. After logout I'm staying on the same route and I would like to get away.

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the same page when you click on logout.

(Some code like this should work, but it's probably not the best way.)

`

```
let currentUrl:string = this.router.url;
this.router.navigateByUrl('/somewhere-else').then(() => {
    this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
});
```

`

A better way :

It better to use `onSameUrlNavigation:'reload'` on built-in Angular Router configuration. And on your route add `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'`
Then you can simply navigate to the same url.

For more information about, I encourage you to read [this](https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2)

Comment: This doesn't look nice. I'd say this is bad. I'd like to find nicer solution

Comment: @user1325696 I edited the post, with a better solution so.